# Change entire column in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a data frame where one column looks like this:

```
structure(list(Concentration = c("XY309 ref 6M", "XY309 ref 5M", 
"XY309 ref 4M", "XY309 ref 3.5M", "XY309 ref 3M", "XY309 ref 2.5M", 
"XY309 ref 2M", "XY309 ref 1M", "XY309 ref 0M", "XY309 SD 6M", 
"XY309 SD 5M", "XY309 SD 4M", "XY309 SD 3.5M", "XY309 SD 3M", 
"XY309 SD 2.5M", "XY309 SD 2M", "XY309 SD 1M", "XY309 SD 0M")), row.names = c(NA, 
18L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to change the entire column so that it only contains the last numeric values (6, 5, 4, 3.5, etc.) without the "M"s. Something like this:

```
structure(list(Concentration = c("6", "5", "4", "3.5", "3", "2.5", 
"2", "1", "0", "6", "5", "4", "3.5", "3", "2.5", "2", "1", "0"
)), row.names = c(NA, 18L), class = "data.frame")
```

I also need the solution to be aplicable to other datasets where the column has different strings with the "M" and the numeric value at the end always being there.
How would I utilize `regex` (or something else) to solve this?
Help is much appreciated!

Comment: simething like this perhaps? `gsub( "^.*([0-9]+)[a-zA-Z]+$", "\\1", "XY309 ref 6M")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the number using  `str_extract` :

```
as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(df$Concentration, '\\d+(\\.\\d+)?(?=M)'))
#[1] 6.0 5.0 4.0 3.5 3.0 2.5 2.0 1.0 0.0 6.0 5.0 4.0 3.5 3.0 2.5 2.0 1.0 0.0
```

`\\d+` - 1 or more than 1 digit

`(\\.\\d+)?` - optional decimal value

`(?=M)` - positive lookahead to look for literal `"M"`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I still need to get comfortable with `regex`...